# Can IIS be installed on the Home Premium Edition of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis

Is it possible to install IIS onto the Home Premium Edition of Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.  [Here is a TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx) from the Microsoft which explains installing IIS 7 on Windows 7 Home Premium, Starter & Basic.

Comment: Thank you, my initial investigations suggested that that a higher edition of windows was needed. Have you or anyone you know actually installed IIS on Windows 7 Home Premium edition?

Comment: @tkyle Yes, works fine on both Vista and 7 Home Premium. You are limited in the number of simultaneous requests (I think it's 3) and I think it doesn't do Windows Authentication, but it's suitable for development and testing.